# error message " 'y' is not declared." in vb.net

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm having a weird problem. I have some code in Visual Studio 2012 express edition in a WPF app written with VisualBasic.Net.

```
Private Sub txtColProvGenCompany_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles txtColProvGenCompany.TextChanged

    ProvNewEditing()
End Sub
```

But when I try to run the application it says that it can't build because the `y` from `txtConProvGenCompan***y***.TextChanged`. The error message is

> `y` is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

and shows only that character underlined in my code.

any ideas?

Comment: weird.. If the code you provided is completely accurate, you should submit a bug report.

Comment: You may have an invisible character there, or something like that. Try deleting the offending string, and re-typing it.

Comment: well... i think i solved it. The code was written between a #Region directive. i just deleted that directive and the problem disappear. i don't know if this is normal or a bug.

Comment: and now i write the directive again and there is no problem. XD that was weird.

Comment: I'm starting to believe we will all be deceptioned by VS 2012 and Win 8

Comment: Sometimes if the background compiler fires while you are typing, and doesn't update again properly, it still "sees" a previous version of the code when it last executed before you finished typing.  I have seen this happen multiple times in VS 2008/2010.  You can always try doing a clean and rebuild to see if it clears up the problem, or if that doesn't work, close and reopen Visual Studio.